# I need to find out who last updated a mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I can get a last update time from TABLES in `information_schema`.  Can I get a USER who updated the database or a table?

Comment: Not unless you record it yourself, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

As Amadan mentioned, I'm pretty sure there isn't a way to do this unless you record it yourself. However, this is a pretty straightforward thing to do: Whenever you perform an `UPDATE` query, also log in a separate table the user (as well as any other relevant information) that you want to record via an additional MySQL query. Something like this (written in PHP as you didn't specify a language, but the MySQL can be exported anywhere) will work:

```
// The update query
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE table SET `col` = ? WHERE `col` = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($var1, $var2));
// Something in table has just been updated; record user's id and time of update
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO log (userid, `time`) VALUES (?, NOW())");
$stmt->execute(array($userid));
```

Comment: I am trying to create a shell script to monitor changes to a set of databases that are maintained by multiple users and multiple applications.  I can use php @Tim.  Thank you for your answers.  I think I need to extract a date from the .ibd files.  I tried stat -c '%y' filename  and that works fine.  Now I need to work out how to extract just the date from the result which was 2015-08-08 15:09:05.842890947 +1000